# Mongodb remove reference of corrupt shard

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded Mongo 3.0.14 setup

- 2 QueryRouter
- 1 Config server
- 3 Cluster (2 data node + 1 arbiter) each with 2TB

How to remove 3rd cluster without draining process? I am okay with the data loss on cluster 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go "under the hood". Shutdown everything else than config server (mongoS, mongoD on shards).

At Config server, go to config database and there shards -collection. Remove wanted line (shard).

Then you need to remove other traces to that removed shard, from chunks -collection (but way that your shard still works):

`db.chunks.update({"shard":"<your removed shard -name>},{$set:{shard:"<name of you other shard>"}},{multi:true})`

and from databases -collection:

`db.databases.update({"primary":"<your removed shard -name>},{$set:{"primary":"<name of you other shard>"}},{multi:true})`

After that, start everything (expect that removed shard) back online. First data bearing nodes (shards) and then last mongoS.

After that, you can start that "removed" shard as single replica set and mongodump data out and import it back to the cluster.. And you get back your "missing" data.

Comment: Thanks @jjussi; We have removed chunks with backup for 3 shard. 

Following is one of the chunk record removed
`{"_id": "DB.Audit-_id_MinKey", "min": {"_id": MinKey()}, "max": {"_id": -9220763799516832079L}, "ns": "DB.Audit", "shard": "mastercluster3", "lastmodEpoch": ObjectId("5861f345644e6b02bc4fabdb"), "lastmod": Timestamp(622, 0)}`

Comment: Related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861047/remove-inaccessible-mongo-shard/3864124 Actually I tried your proposal (on version 4.2). In principle it seems to work, however when I run afterwards `db.collection.getShardDistribution()` then I get an error "collection is not sharded" Any Idea what could be missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is difference at version 4.2, but that basically means that there is no record of sharding of that collection at config-database.